# How to get the status after sending data to external server rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, external

In my rails (3.2.13) app I send data to an external server using a form, then the external server process the data I sent and shows that the result is ok or not, I need to save that result or status to my rails app database, but I'm not sure about how to redirect to another page when the process in the external server is done.

I have a function to ask the server if the process of that data went ok using the reference or id that  I sent in the first place using the form but as I said I don't know how to redirect after the process is finish...

please help me

Comment: Will you please provide more details? What is this `external server`?

Comment: Its a server in another ip address, I don't know what is being executed there but I send the data using form post, the server validates my data and if everything went right shows me an internal form using the data that I sent in it... feel free to tell me if I'm still not clear enough :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some core Ruby libraries to make a subsequent request on the same endpoint to determine the status code of your request. Try the following, cited in whole from [Ruby Inside](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html):

```
# Basic REST.
# Most REST APIs will set semantic values in response.body and response.code.
require "net/http"

http = Net::HTTP.new("api.restsite.com")

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/users")
request.set_form_data({"users[login]" => "quentin"})
response = http.request(request)
# Use nokogiri, hpricot, etc to parse response.body.

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/users/1")
response = http.request(request)
# As with POST, the data is in response.body.

request = Net::HTTP::Put.new("/users/1")
request.set_form_data({"users[login]" => "changed"})
response = http.request(request)

request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new("/users/1")
response = http.request(request)
```

Once you've instantiated a `response` object, you can operate on it in the following manner:

```
response.code #=> returns HTTP response code
```